# django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: PostgreSQL 12 or later is required (found 11.19)

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am getting this error when I try to run my django server locally: "django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: PostgreSQL 12 or later is required (found 11.19).". The local django server is connected to a postgres instance hosted on ElephantSQL.

I have installed psycopg2-binary==2.9.6.

But when I run "python manage.py runserver", I get the error "django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: PostgreSQL 12 or later is required (found 11.19).". I tried upgrading my computer's postgres with homebrew, up to 12.5. This did not fix the problem, as I still get the same error (which still mentions 11.19). I do not know what instance of postgres this 11.19 refers to, and how to update it to 12 or above.

Ideas?

Note- another stack overflow post about this suggested downgrading my django version from a 4 to a 3, but this seems like a bad way to fix it.

Comment: 1) *I do not know what instance of postgres this 11.19 refers to ...* see *The local django server is connected to a postgres instance hosted on ElephantSQL.* 2) What is exact version of Django you are using?

Comment: Django 4.1 supports Postgres 11+ per [Release Notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/releases/4.1/). Django 4.2 supports Postgres 12+ per [Release Notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/releases/4.2/).

Comment: the django version in the project is Django==4.2.1

Comment: Then you will need Postgres 12+ or use Django 4.1. Look before you leap, read the Release Notes they are there to give you  the heads up on changes.

Answer (score 8):

You need to downgrade your Django or upgrade your PostgreSQL version. I think downgrading django will be easier. For that you can do the following:

```
pip uninstall django
```

After uninstalling, you need to reinstall django but of lower version, for that you can use the following command:

```
pip install django==4.1
```

Django 4.2 does not support PostgreSQL lower than 12(as you said that you have Django 4.2), but Django 4.1 can use PostgreSQL 11.xx. Here is the documentation:

for Django 4.2:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/databases/#postgresql-notes

for Django 4.1:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/databases/#postgresql-notes

Comment: This answer isn't. 1) You don't want to downgrade Postgres as it is already too far behind. 2) You left out Django 4.1 which  supports Postgres 11+

Comment: I had a similar issue with a remote MySQL db which I couldn't upgrade. This helped. Thanks :)

Comment: You need to downgrade django or upgrade postgresql version. Downgrading postgresql won't solve the problem.

Comment: above answer worked for me .

Answer (score -1):

ElephantSQL is currently using postgres server 11.19

> psql (15.4, server 11.19 (Ubuntu 11.19-1.pgdg20.04+1)) SSL connection
> (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, compression: off)
> Type "help" for help.

You need to connect to a postgres server version 12 or higher.